# Getting Volume in Google Books by ISBN

Tags: php, api, google-books

Recently Google changes almost all their APIs and now I can't achieve things any longer.

How to get books volume by ISBN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This request Google Books API using a single required parameter, "q", which will search for volumes that contain this text string. However, there are special keywords you can specify in the search terms to search in particular fields.

The one you're looking for is `isbn:` which returns results where the text following this keyword is the ISBN number. For instance, `isbn:0521609283`.

You can perform the volume search by sending an HTTP GET request to the following URI:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0521609283

---

[[+] more info on how to perform a search through Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#WorkingVolumes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I found the solution some time ago but not matter your answer is valid and you got the points